# Hours on a day between dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following columns: gkey, ata, atd

ata and atd are both date times.

I want to work out hours per day that something arrived before it left.

**Example data:**

```
+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| gkey    | ata                     | atd                     |
+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 1142227 | 14/06/2017 17:30:00.000 | 15/06/2017 05:30:00.000 |
+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 1322667 | 18/01/2018 16:17:00.000 | 18/01/2018 20:45:00.000 |
+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 1339468 | 26/02/2018 23:57:00.000 | 27/02/2018 11:35:00.000 |
+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

**Expected Result:**

```
14/06/2017 - 6.5 hours
15/06/2017 - 5.5 hours
18/01/2018 - 4.5 hours
26/02/2018 - 0.05 hours
27/02/2018 - 11.58 hours
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select gkey, ata, atd,
             ata as day_start,
             (case when cast(ata as date) = cast(atd as date)
                   then atd
                   else dateadd(day, 1, cast(ata as date))
              end) as day_end
      from t
      union all
      select gkey, day_end, atd,
             day_end as day_start,
             (case when cast(day_end as date) = cast(atd as date)
                   then day_end
                   else dateadd(day, 1, cast(day_end as date))
              end) as day_end
      from cte
      where day_start < cast(atd as date)
     )
select cte.*,
       datediff(minute, day_start, day_end) / 60.0 as num_hours
from cte;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/23648) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, almost there, just had to do modify the num_hours part slightly:
`datediff(minute, day_start, (CASE WHEN CAST(atd as Date) = CAST(ata as Date) THEN atd else day_end end)) / 60.0 as num_hours`